# How Scala App trait and main works internally?

Tags: scala

Hi I'm newbie in Scala.

As far as I know there are 2ways to make entry point in scala, one is define main method with object and the other is extending ***App*** trait.

I wondered how ***App*** trait works, so I checked the source for ***App*** trait, but there are full of confusing code...

The code said that the App has ***initCodes*** which are extended from ***App*** trait, and these are added in ***delayedInit*** method that inherited from ***DelayedInit***. Also the ***App*** trait has main method, which will be entry point.

But the What confusing me are

1. Who call ***delayedInit***? Is it called before the main method is called?(I guess Yes)
2. Why ***initCodes*** is ***ListBuffer*** not a element? I think there is only one entry point in application, so I don't think it should be plural.
3. Where can I check these knowledge? I tried to search in document but I couldn't

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 1. Who call delayedInit? Is it called before the main method is called?(I guess Yes)

The `delayedInit` would be called automatically by the Scala compiler as the initialisation code of the object/class that extends the `DelayedInit` trait. I expand more on this answer below.

> 2. Why initCodes is ListBuffer not a element? I think there is only one entry point in application, so I don't think it should be plural.

Because it is possible to have a hierarchy of classes, where the initialisation code of each class in the hierarchy gets executed as part of executing the program. An example is also provided below.

> 3. Where can I check these knowledge? I tried to search in document but I couldn't.

I got to learn about the dynamics by reading the Scala docs and the links it points to. For example this https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/tag/v2.11.0 and https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4330?jql=labels%20%3D%20delayedinit%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20unresolved

I would now try to expatiate more on the answer above by going into more details into the workings of `DelayedInit`, and how the JVM specifies entry points to programs.

First of all, we have to understand that when Scala is run on the JVM, it still has to adhere to the JVM requirement for defining the entry point to your program, which is to provide the JVM with a class with a main method with signature of `public static void main(String[])`. Even though when we use the `App` trait, it might appear as if we are getting away from do this, but this is just an illusion, the JVM still needs to have access to a method with the signature `public static void main(String[])`. It is just that by extending `App` together with the mechanism of `DelayedInit`, Scala can provide this method on our behalf.

Second, it is also good to reiterate that code snippets found in the body of a class (or object) definition, would be the initialisation code of such a class/object and would be executed automatically when such is instantiated. In Java, it is more or less the code you put in the constructor block.

So for a class:

```
class Foo {
// code.
def method = ???
}
```

Whatever `code` is, it will be executed automatically when you call `new Foo`.

In case of an object

```
object Foo {
// code.
def method = ???
}
```

The `code` will be executed automatically without you having to call `new` since Scala would automatically make a singleton instance called `Foo` available for you.

So basically if anything is in the body definition, it gets executed automatically. You do not need to explicitly execute it.

Now to the `DelayedInit` trait. One thing to be aware of is that it provides us a mechanism to perform what can be called a compiler trick, where certain part of our code gets rewritten. This is one of the reason why it could be confusing to reason about. Because when you use it, what actually gets executed by the Scala compiler is not the code you reading but a slight modification of it. To understand what is going on, you then need to understand the ways the compiler alters the code.

The trick, the `DelayedInit` trait allows us to perform is to take the code that is part of the body of a class/object definition and turn it, into an argument that is passed by name, to the method `delayedInit` defined on `DelayedInit`.

Basically it rewrites this:

```
object Foo {
// some code
}
```

into

```
object Foo {
// delayedInt({some code})
}
```

This means instead of having `// some code` executed automatically, `delayedInt` is the method that is called automatically with `// some code` passed to it as arguments.

So anything that extends `DelayedInit` would have its initialisation code replaced by the method call `delayedInt` with the initialisation code passed as an argument. Hence why nobody needs to explicitly call the `delayedInt` method.

Now let use see how this then tie to the `App` trait and how the `App` trait is used to provide the entry point to a Scala application.

As you will notice, the `delayedInit` method on the `DelayedInit` trait does not provide any implementation. Hence the actual behaviour of `delayedInit` when it is called needs to be provided by something else that extends `DelayedInit`.

The `App` trait is such an implementation. And what does the `App` trait do? Two important thing related to the topic of discussion:

1. It provides an implementation of `delayedInit` which takes the initialisation code it is passed, and puts it in a `ListBuffer`.
2. It provides the main method `def main(args: Array[String])` which satisfy the requirement of the JVM to have a method with `public static void main(String[])` to serve as the entry point to a program. And what this main method does, is to execute whatever code placed in the ListBuffer.

The above characteristics of the `App` trait means that any object/class that extends it would have its initialisation code passed to `delayedInit`, which would then add it into a ListBuffer, and then the object/class extending it would now have a main method, which when called (most of the time by the JVM as the entry point) would run through the code in the ListBuffer and execute it.

Basically it turns this:

```
object Foo {
// some code
}
```

into this

```
object Foo {

// the implementation of delayedInt is to put `// some code` into a list buffer
delayedInt (// some code)

def main(args: Array[String]) = {
// the implementation below just runs through and execute the code found in list buffer that would have been populated by the call to delayedInt and 
??? 
  }
}
```

So why have a List buffer to store the code to be executed? Because, as I said above it is possible to have a hierarchy of classes, where the initialisation code of each class in the hierarchy gets executed as part of executing the program. To see this in action.

Given the following code snippet:

```
class AnotherClass {
  println("Initialising AnotherClass")
}
trait AnotherTrait {
  println("Initialising AnotherTrait")
}
trait YetAnotherTrait {
  println("Initialising YetAnotherTrait")
} 

object Runner extends AnotherClass with AnotherTrait with YetAnotherTrait with App {
  println("Hello world")
}
```

When run would output the following:

```
Initialising AnotherClass
Initialising AnotherTrait
Initialising YetAnotherTrait
Hello world
```

So the individual initialisation code in the hierarchy that consists of  `AnotherClass`, `AnotherTrait` and `YetAnotherTrait` gets added to the `initCode` list buffer, via the `delayedInit` method of the `App` trait, and then they get executed by the main method also provided by the `App` trait.

As you would have noticed by peeking into the source code, the whole mechanism of `DelayedInt` is deprecated and schedule for removal in the future.

Comment: Perfect answer! I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

**delayedInit:-**

> The init hook. This saves all initialization code for execution within
>   `main`. This method is normally never called directly from user code.
>   Instead it is called as compiler-generated code for those classes and
>   objects (but not traits) that inherit from the `DelayedInit` trait and
>   that do not themselves define a `delayedInit` method.

[App scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.2/src/library/scala/App.scala#L1)

`delayedInit` is deprecated since `2.11.0`. Also, it has some outstanding [bugs](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4680?jql=labels%20%3D%20delayedinit%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20unresolved) which are not fixed.

**initCodes:-**

I am not sure about the reason for defining the `initCodes` as ListBuffer.