# I received the error "error: expected class or object definition" in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, matrix

I have the below code but I received the error: expected class or object definition. and it referenced to Val matrix. what is the problem?

```
object Main{
 def squaresHaveNoDuplicates(matrix: Array[Array[Int]]) = {
    val rowBlocks = matrix.grouped(3).toArray
    println(rowBlocks)
 }
}      

val matrix= Array(
Array(0, 5, 0, 3, 0, 9, 0, 2, 6),
Array(3, 8, 9, 4, 2, 0, 1, 5, 7),
Array(4, 0, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9),
Array(0, 1, 3, 7, 9, 8, 0, 0, 4),
Array(0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0),
Array(0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0),
Array(0, 0, 1, 9, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0),
Array(9, 3, 5, 6, 4, 0, 8, 0, 1),
Array(0, 0, 2, 8, 7, 0, 0, 0, 5)

squaresHaveNoDuplicates(matrix)
```

Edit: even i try a simple code like :

```
val str= Array(1,2,3)
```

I receive the same error in REPL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are simple syntax errors.

```scala
object Main extends App {
  def squaresHaveNoDuplicates(matrix: Seq[Seq[Int]]) = {
    val rowBlocks = matrix.grouped(3).toSeq
    println(rowBlocks)
  }

  val matrix = Seq(
    Seq(0, 5, 0, 3, 0, 9, 0, 2, 6),
    Seq(3, 8, 9, 4, 2, 0, 1, 5, 7),
    Seq(4, 0, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9),
    Seq(0, 1, 3, 7, 9, 8, 0, 0, 4),
    Seq(0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0),
    Seq(0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0),
    Seq(0, 0, 1, 9, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0),
    Seq(9, 3, 5, 6, 4, 0, 8, 0, 1),
    Seq(0, 0, 2, 8, 7, 0, 0, 0, 5)
  )

  squaresHaveNoDuplicates(matrix)

}
```

1. Code like value assignment, `val matrix = Array(...)`, cannot be located outside of an `class` or `object`. Thus the error message.
2. Missing parentheses for definition of the outer `matrix: Array`
3. `println` won't print the content of an `Array` and I replaced it with `Seq`
4. `Main` won't run unless it extends `App` or defines `main` method. JVM needs to have an entry point into the program and the convention is that this is a `def main(arg: Array[String])`. Scala `App` is using so called delayed initialization but it is phased out in [Scala 3](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/delayed-init.html). Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53468358/how-scala-app-trait-and-main-works-internally)

Comment: Great. Can you explain about App?