# Why does println(array) have strange output in Scala?

Tags: scala

when I use println to print the content of an Array in Scala I received some strange results. I know how fix this in java. but the solution in java gives me an error in scala. the output of println is something like:

```
List([I@5ec77191, [I@4642b71d, [I@1450078a)
```

Comment: Please show the complete code

Comment: My guess it's related to previous question that was posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70015532/i-received-the-error-error-expected-class-or-object-definition-in-scala

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4) Note that, though the dupe target is for Java, it's really the same issue. The Java solutions explored in the dupe could be tailored to perhaps use some of Scala's advanced features.

Answer (score 3):

Scala's Array type is exactly the same as Java's, so if you call toString on it, that is what you get. An easy way to print the contents is to convert the arrays to another type of collection first, e. g. `Vector` or `ArraySeq`.

Answer (score 1):

Collections in Scala have `mkString` . This applies for Array.

```scala
val arr: Array[String] = 
 ???
val arrs: Array[Array[String]] = 
 ???

println(arr.mkString(",")) //print the contents of just one array

arrs
  .foreach(arr => println(arr.mkString(",")) //print something similar to your example
```